# how can I change tint color of only one row of a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift5

I have a table with times and I just want to highlight the line with the current date with a different text color (tint color - not the background color). Everything works so far - only the drawing color cannot be changed? The background color is used to highlight other information.

```
    customCell.descriptionField.text = "\(entriesSection.events![indexPath.row].title!)"
    customCell.descriptionField.tintColor = .blue    /// ??? - it does not work!
```

Comment: What type is descriptionField? A UILabel? A UITextField? Are you trying to change the text color?

Comment: First of all: Thanks for the answer. Yes - textField: @IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextField!

Comment: So if you just want to change the text color, why don't you set the textColor property instead of tintColor?